# Is it possible to copy the %+ hash when using named subexpressions?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following regular expression for matching output from `readelf -Ws`:

```
my $regex = qr{  ^\s+(?'Num'\d+):
                  \s+(?'Value'\w+)
                  \s+(?'Size'(?:\d+|0x[0-9a-fA-f]+))
                  \s+(?'Type'\w+)
                  \s+(?'Bind'\w+)
                  \s+(?'Vis'\w+)
                  \s+(?'Ndx'\w+)
                  \s+(?'Name'\S+)
              }x;
```

... and while it may not be perfect, it suits my needs well enough.

Ideally, the way this would be used is:

```
while( <> ) {
  chomp;
  m{${regex}} || next;
  # an implicit assertion here is that length($+{Name}) > 0
  if(   $+{Type} =~ m{something}
     && $+{Bind} =~ m{something}
     ...
```

... however, `%+` gets clobbered after the first regular expression.  I'm not sure how to make a copy of the hash that underlies `%+`.  Is it possible, and if so how would I do it?

Obviously the following can be done:

```
while( <> ) {
  chomp;
  my ($Num, $Value, $Size, $Type, $Bind, $Vis, $Ndx, $Name) = ($_ =~ m{${regex}});
  next unless defined( $Name );

  if(   $Type =~ m{something}
     && $Bind =~ m{something}
     ...
```

... but I rather like using named subexpressions because it can help make the regular expression self documenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%captures = %+;
```

```
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

local $_ = 'abc123';

my @captures;
while (/(?'Letters'\pL+)|(?'Digits'\pN+)/g) {
   my %captures = %+;
   push @captures, \%captures;
}

print(Dumper(\@captures));
```

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'Letters' => 'abc'
          },
          {
            'Digits' => '123'
          }
        ];
```

---

Or since only the defined fields are present, you can use

```
%captures = ( %captures, %+ );
```

or

```
$captures{$_} = $+{$_} for keys %+;
```

```
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

local $_ = 'abc123';

my %captures;
while (/(?'Letters'\pL+)|(?'Digits'\pN+)/g) {
   %captures = ( %captures, %+ );
}

print(Dumper(\%captures));
```

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Letters' => 'abc',
          'Digits' => '123'
        };
```

Comment: hrm.  I swear I tried doing the obvious thing and it left `%captures` in an undefined state.  I'll try it again, thanks for the swift response.

Comment: bah.  It worked.  I dunno where I went wrong the first time, but it's working fine now.